# Looking for an azure service to manage web push notifications

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-eventhub

I'm implementing a notifications feature in an html5 web app I'm working on.

The feature requirements is to receive push notifications (strings) from the server and display them immediately on the user interface (to all clients), without saving them anywhere else.

I'm looking for a managed service on Azure cloud that allows send/onMessage functionalities very similar to WebSockets, that can be accessed directly by the browser.

I've tried using event-hubs, but that solution requires a node.js/SignalR wrapper which I can't use for this specific feature.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure what you're asking, or how Azure comes into play. What, exactly, do you mean by "real time web notifications?" There are lots of technologies out there, and this can be seen as a very broad question, and a tool/framework recommendation question as well. As written, I don't see this being on-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm looking for something exactly like event-hubs that can be accessed directly by the browser (without using SignalR or the node.js wrapper).
If that's impossible at the moment it's an acceptable answer as well.

Comment: 1) Please *edit your question* with clarifications. 2) What you just added doesn't really clarify anything, as you already stated that in your original question. What does "real time" mean?

Comment: Editted, hope now it's better

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to implement a real-time notification feature for HTML5 App without any middleware like WebApp in Node/SignalR to connect a message queue like EventHubs. However, there seems to be not any solution for the needs without any backend services as HTTP middleware for browser if using EventHubs or other services like PubSub in Redis.

Per my experience, a only available solution is that using [pouchdb](https://pouchdb.com/) within browser to synchronize with [CouchDb on Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/partners/bitnami/couchdb/) to implement a PubSub service as notification service.

There is a opensource project on GitHub which you can refer to, please move to https://github.com/MattCollins84/couch-pubsub.

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the response, will check it out soon.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome M52 and beyond started supporting the VAPID protocol, refer to  https://chromestatus.com/feature/5573539073622016.

It seems that Azure does not yet provide VAPID support. As an alternative you can look into Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) which you can connect with Azure Notification Hub.

More on Firebase Cloud Messaging and web push html client: https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client

More on Azure Notification Hub and connecting it with FCM:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-android-push-notification-google-fcm-get-started

VAPID stands for: Voluntary Application server Identification for web Push. Refer to https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8292